# Replace a string with list of string from an array php

Tags: php, laravel-mail

I have a php file with codeblocks like

```
$error_arr =  array();
foreach{
    try{
            INSERT DATA
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $error_arr = $e;
    }
}


$data_arr = [
        'filename' => $filename,
        'user_name' => $user_name,
        'error' => $error_arr
    ];
```

Here, exception will be catched and stored in $error_arr and later into data_arr['error'].

In mail file, I am replacing as

```
  $array_from_to = array (
            '[[USER_NAME]]' => $this->data_arr['user_name'],
            '[[FILENAME]]' => $this->data_arr['filename'],
            '[[ERROR]]' => $this->data_arr['error']
        );

        $data->content = str_replace(array_keys($array_from_to), $array_from_to, $data->content);



   {{OTHER STUFF of mail content}}

    [[ERROR]]

   {{OTHER STUFF of mail content}}
```

Now, in this error block I want to display all error from the array. As this number of error can be from 0 to any number. But, currently It display only the last error. How, can I show all error as an ordered lists.

Comment: `$error_arr[] = $e;`?

Comment: Spare the array_keys call and just use `strtr()` for replacing.

Comment: So your question is how to push data into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes, the first is to store an array of errors - you currently overwrite the error each time...

```
$error_arr[] = $e;
```

The second is how to build the error array into a string for the replace, a simple way is to use `implode()`...

```
'[[ERROR]]' => implode(",", $this->data_arr['error'])
```

You may want to change the way it's displayed, but this will just provide a comma separated list of errors.

**Update:**

If you want to lay out the error, you can add a simple `foreach()` loop to build up a string in the format your after...

```
$error = '';
foreach ( $data_arr['error'] as $key => $text )    {
    $error .= ($key+1)." - ". $text.PHP_EOL;
}
```

and then

```
'[[ERROR]]' => $error
```

Comment: @mickmackusa, problem I have with that is it then fixes how the errors are presented.  Leaving it as an array means that the caller can present the errors in whatever way they need.

Comment: @NigelRen Ok I get it. But, can you suggest me how can I represent those error with numeric lists. As comma(,)  separated are not clearly visible at the moment.